# Оптимизация времени изменения размера изображения

Tags: c++, изображения, resize

В буфер потокового кодировщика непрерывно поступают изображения (снимки рабочего стола). Так как пользователь может поменять разрешение экрана во время трансляции, ширина и высота буфера кадра, подаваемого на кодировщик, фиксированы, и входящий кадр нужно приводить к размерам исходящего с сохранением пропорций, заполняя чёрным неиспользуемые области исходящего кадра.

Проблема в том, что скейлинг занимает очень много времени:
[image: timings]

Данный тестовый вывод получен в результате такого кода:

```
bool streamer::Push(unsigned char *source, unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
    int start = clock(); // время начала операции

    Canvas image(width, height);
    image.Copy(source, width, height);
    double h_rel, v_rel, mod;
    unsigned int t_width, t_height, v_pad, h_pad;
    h_rel = (double)framebuf.Width() / width;
    v_rel = (double)framebuf.Height() / height;
    mod = (h_rel < v_rel)?h_rel:v_rel; // отношение размеров исходящего и входящего изображения

    if( mod == 1){
        h_pad = v_pad = 0;
        t_width = width;
        t_height = height;
    }
    else{
        t_width = image.Width() * mod;
        t_height = image.Height() * mod;
        h_pad = (framebuf.Width() - t_width) / 2;
        v_pad = (framebuf.Height() - t_height) / 2 * framebuf.Line();
    }
    int prepare = clock(); // время подготовки
    image.Scale(t_width, t_height);
    int scaling = clock(); // время изменения масштаба
    for(unsigned int l = 0; l < image.Height(); l++){
        framebuf.WriteLine(h_pad, v_pad + l*framebuf.Line(), image.Data(l*image.Line()), image.Line());
    }
    int finalizing = clock(); // время завершения
    printf("prepare: %d\nscaling: %d\nfinalizing: %d\n",(prepare-start),(scaling - prepare),(finalizing-scaling));

    framestack.lock();
    unsigned int count = images.size();
    images.push_back(vpx_image_t());
    if(!vpx_img_alloc(&images[count], VPX_IMG_FMT_I420, framebuf.Width(), framebuf.Height(), 1)){
        images.erase(images.begin()+count);
        framestack.unlock();
        return false;
    }
    colorspaces::BGRtoI420(framebuf.Width(), framebuf.Height(), framebuf.Data(), &images[count].planes[0], &images[count].planes[1], &images[count].planes[2]);   
    framestack.unlock();
    return true;
}
```

Код скейлинга:

```
void Canvas::Scale(unsigned int w, unsigned int h){
    unsigned char* scaled = (unsigned char*)malloc(w * h * colors);

    float w_factor = w / (float)width;
    float h_factor = h / (float)height;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < h; ++i){
        float fY = ((float) i) / h_factor;
        unsigned int iY = (unsigned int)fY;

        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < w; ++j){
            float fX = ((float) j) / w_factor;
            int iX = (unsigned int) fX;

            pixel q11(this, iY, iX);
            pixel q12(this, iY + 1, iX);
            pixel q21(this, iY, iX + 1);
            pixel q22(this, iY + 1, iX + 1);

            unsigned char r1_b = (iX + 1 - fX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q11.b + (fX - iX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q21.b;
            unsigned char r1_g = (iX + 1 - fX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q11.g + (fX - iX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q21.g;
            unsigned char r1_r = (iX + 1 - fX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q11.r + (fX - iX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q21.r;

            unsigned char r2_b = (iX + 1 - fX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q12.b + (fX - iX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q22.b;
            unsigned char r2_g = (iX + 1 - fX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q12.g + (fX - iX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q22.g;
            unsigned char r2_r = (iX + 1 - fX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q12.r + (fX - iX)/(iX + 1 - iX)*q22.r;

            unsigned char b = (iY + 1 - fY)/(iY + 1 - iY)*r1_b + (fY - iY)/(iY + 1 - iY)*r2_b;
            unsigned char g = (iY + 1 - fY)/(iY + 1 - iY)*r1_g + (fY - iY)/(iY + 1 - iY)*r2_g;
            unsigned char r = (iY + 1 - fY)/(iY + 1 - iY)*r1_r + (fY - iY)/(iY + 1 - iY)*r2_r;

            scaled[i*w*colors + j*colors + 0] = b;
            scaled[i*w*colors + j*colors + 1] = g;
            scaled[i*w*colors + j*colors + 2] = r;
        }
    }
    Specify(scaled);
    Setup(w,h);
}
```

Структура `pixel`, используемая классом `Canvas`:

```
struct pixel{
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char r;
    pixel(Canvas *c, unsigned int h, unsigned int w){
        b = *(c->Data(h*c->Line() + w*c->Colors() + 0));
        g = *(c->Data(h*c->Line() + w*c->Colors() + 1));
        r = *(c->Data(h*c->Line() + w*c->Colors() + 2));
    }
};
```

Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать алгоритм изменения размера. Или может есть какая-нибудь легковесная библиотека, которая может быстро выполнить данную операцию? Хотя бы до 50 мс, а то 370-400 это сильный перебор, и процессор i3 этот алгоритм грузит на 25%...

[UPDATE]

Пока остановился на функции OpenCV `resize`. Хотелось бы конечно сделать свой алгоритм с высоким быстродействием, но проект надо двигать дальше и времени мало... так что пока временное решение - это OpenCV

Comment: Стоп, если вы "заполняете черным"  - тогда скейлинг не нужен, если делаете скейлинг - тогда заполнение чёрным отпадает... Заполняйте чёрным - это будет быстрее.

Comment: Например  `pixel(...){ if ((w > w1) ||  (h > h1)) { r=0;g=0;b=0; return; } ...` - заполнение чёрным зоны за гранью w1 h1

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет-нет, тут другое. Например, исходящий размер указан как 1280х960 (4 к 3), на вход поступает 1920 х 1080  (широкоформатка), Приведя 1920 к 1280, высота без изменения пропорций будет 720, при этом чёрным надо заполнить (960-720)/2 сверху и снизу... Или я не так Вас понял...

Comment: Избавьтесь от float в вашем методе скейла (float fX = ((float) j) / w_factor;). Целочисленные операции намного быстрее, чем операции с числами с плавающий точкой. Также ваш метод не выглядит самым оптимальным вариантом. Можете найти библиотеку специализированную, где такие операции оптимизированные на ассемблере.

Comment: К предыдущему остаётся добавить, что повторяющееся выражение в скобках лучше вынести в переменную, поскольку компилятор врядли оптимизирует выражение и вынесет повторы вычислений (я за `(iX + 1 - fX)/(iX + 1 - iX)`, `i*w*colors + j*colors + 0` и т д)

Comment: в коде явно много "однотипных конструкций". sse поможет ускорить это сразу в раза 2-3 (а при хорошем подходе и до 4).

Comment: @KoVadim, ну с SSE я ещё не работал. Это на асме писать надо, да? Пока не представляю как это сюда вписать... А старые ноуты, нетбуки SSE поддерживают?

Comment: нет, можно писать на с/с++ - есть такая штука, как инстрики - просто специальные функции. Они помогут складывать или перемножать сразу по 4 пары чисел (а то и более других действий). Старые ноуты - это очень размытое понятие, но если на этом ноуте хоть XP работает, то там есть sse (как минимум минимальное). Если работает хром 40+, то есть как минимум sse2 - а этого хватит для многого. Я ускорял с помощью sse преобразование yuv-rgb - дало около 2.5 раз ускорения.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, изучу этот вопрос...

Comment: Возможно http://fastcpp.blogspot.com/2011/06/bilinear-pixel-interpolation-using-sse.html это поможет вам.

Comment: @Iceman Не забудьте отписаться по результатм улучшения)

Comment: @KoVadim, как считаете, если подать на вход не массив байт, а OpenCV Mat, отскейлить его средствами того же OpenCV, скопировать на другой Mat уже с паддингами, достать BGR и перевести его в I420 - быстрее не станет?

Comment: может и будет. А может и нет - копирование не бесплатно. Надо тестировать.

Comment: @KoVadim, OpenCV `resize` даёт тайминг 12-30 мс и вдвое меньшую загрузку процессора... Эх, научиться бы так делать своими руками ))

Comment: логично, что раньше было 25% (у Вас 4 ядерный проц, скорее всего i5).  Время между захватами кадров выставлено в 24-50 мс, и когда обработка по 12-30, то это дает нагрузку в пол ядра.